# lxmed data files?

Tags: lxde

[LXPanel Menu-plugin Wiki](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Main_Menu) describes how to edit file to configure the menu. Additionally, it states:

> One can download and compile LXMED, a menu editor for LXDE

I am able to change the menu by editing the files directly but using lxmed has no effect on the menu. The menu info shown by lxmed does not match menu content. What is lxmed actually working with?

Answer (score 1):

Lxmed puts your application.desktop in the wrong directory that is /usr/local/share/applications instead of usr/share/applications. You have to cut / paste your file.desktop as root once created in the right directory